# Get object nested inside another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I get `Photos` object? I have tried `{{ item.image.Photos[0].image }}` it doesn't work

[image]

**TypeScript**

```
listHotelPhotos( hotel_id ){
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: 'Loading...' });
    loader.present();
    this.api.hotelPhotos( hotel_id ).subscribe( response => {
      this.hotelImages = response.HotelImages;
      this.Rooms = response.Rooms;
      console.log( response.Rooms );
      loader.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-grid class="select-room-types">
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of Rooms">
            <ion-col width-100><img src="{{ item.image }}" /></ion-col>
            <div class="caption">
                <ion-grid class="select-room-card">
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col width-75>{{ item.name }}</ion-col>
                        <ion-col width-25>FJ ${{ item.rate }}</ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>
            </div>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Your photos array consists of 1 object always?

Comment: Much better to post (a snippet of) the JSON response than an image.

Comment: @nishantagrawal No

Comment: Then which image you want to display or you want to display all images of photos array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming Rooms is the array you posted an image of, it's just `item.Photos[0].image`

Comment: damn I am so stupid. I think I need sleep. Thank you bro

Comment: happens to the best of us.